# Replacing with gsub and if column element gets empty fill with it a backslash

Tags: r, dplyr, gsub

I have this dataframe as toy example

`dfl=data.frame(x=c("1","2","3","4"),event=c("wrestle/mania","wrestle/mercy","wrestle","wrestle/mercy"))`

Now i want to remove all "wrestle" string in event col.So i am using this code:

`dfl$event = gsub("wrestle","",df$event)`

But I want a backslah if whole string gets replaced as in 3 element of event col

Comment: so for three of the elements the event is just "wrestle"?

Comment: it will delete wrestle and place a backslash in place of it.How to do? _so elements like /mania,/mercy,/,/mercy_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfl %>%
  mutate(event = ifelse(event == "wrestle", 
                        "/", 
                        gsub("wrestle", "", event)))
```

That will give you:

```
  x  event
1 1 /mania
2 2 /mercy
3 3      /
4 4 /mercy
```

Comment: It worked great . Sorry it was forward slash .rest worked `dfl %>%
  mutate(event = ifelse(event == "wrestle", 
                        "/", 
                        gsub("wrestle", "", event)))`